# Calling grails commands from grails events?

Tags: java, events, grails, groovy, build

I need to call a plugin with arguments from a grails event script. How do I do this?

Specifically, I'm trying to hook into `eventCompile` to call `generate-dto --all`, sending `y` to STDIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (and probably slowest) way to do it is to invoke grails in an event handler.  This is a bit tricky, since `generate-dto` generates a compile event, but you can make it conditional on a system property.  A second problem is the required input.  By convention, grails scripts are all supposed to accept `--non-interactive` and not prompt the user, but the dto plugin seems to not follow this.  A workaround for Posix systems like Linux or MacOS X is to pipe in the `yes` command as the grails input.

Here's how I got it working:

```
// scripts/_Events.groovy
eventCompileStart = { args ->
    if (Boolean.valueOf(System.getProperty('in.generate', "false"))) {
        // skip
    } else {
        ['bash', '-c', 'yes | grails -Din.generate=true generate-dto --all'].execute()
    }
}
```

Comment: Oi, more fun command execution. I need this to run on windows, linux, and mac dev environments, but I guess I could pull something off with cmd /c.

Answer (score 0):

Try running whole compilation with `--non-interactive argument`. I tells Grails to skip all the questions and inputs from user eg. if running as job in Jenkins(Hudson). I'm not sure if it will help, but you can try. I used this argument on Hudson to test my app and skip questions about updating plugins.